# Mi función "Buscar" Se queda leyendo el archivo infinitamente C++

Tags: c++

básicamente mi función buscar nunca encuentra el nombre ingresado, y se queda infinitamente recorriendo el archivo (Lo comprobé con dos couts que me demostraban esto mismo)

Mi duda es, como logro que el archivo lea correctamente e identifique si dos cadenas de caracteres son iguales, y en caso de que haya recorrido todo el archivo, no se quede recorriendo la nada misma y se salga del while para llegar al if(existe==0), para así soltar el mensaje de "El alumno ingresado no existe", muchas gracias!

```
struct alumno
{
    char apellidoYNombre[50];
    char grado[50];
    char dojo[50];
    char kata[50];
    char kumite[50];
    int edad;
};

void buscar()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("listado_alumnos.dat","rb");
    cout << "\nIngrese el nombre del alumno: ";
    char apellidoYNombre[50];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(apellidoYNombre);
    alumno a;
    int existe = 0;
    fread(&a, sizeof(alumno), 1, f);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        if(strcmp(apellidoYNombre, a.apellidoYNombre)==0)
        {
            cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
            cout << "Nombre........: " << a.apellidoYNombre << endl;
            cout << "Edad..........: " << a.edad << endl;
            cout << "Grado.........: " << a.grado << endl;
            cout << "Dojo..........: " << a.dojo << endl;
            cout << "Kumite........: " << a.kumite << endl;
            cout << "Kata..........: " << a.kata << endl;
            cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
            existe = 1;
            break;
        }
        fread(&a, sizeof(alumno), 1, f);
    }
    if(existe==0)
    {
        cout << "El alumno ingresado no existe" << endl;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    int opc=0, num1=0, num2=0, edad;
    char apellidoYNombre[50], grado[50], dojo[50];
    FILE *f;

    do
    {
        cout << "\n________________________" << endl;
        cout << "-_-MENU DE OPCIONES-_-" << endl;
        cout << "1) Agregar Alumno" << endl;
        cout << "2) Borrar Alumno" << endl;
        cout << "3) Mostrar lista" << endl;
        cout << "4) Buscar Alumno" << endl;
        cout << "5) Salir" << endl;
        cout << "________________________" << endl;
        cout << "Elija una opción: ";
        cin >> opc;

        switch(opc)
        {
        case 1:
            agregar();
            break;
        case 2:
            eliminar();
            break;
        case 3:
            mostrar();
            break;
        case 4:
            buscar();
            break;
        case 5:
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nLa opción ingresada es incorrecta";
            break;
        }
    } while(opc != 5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cual es la definición de `alumno`?

Comment: @eferion Ahi lo edité, es simple la función, no tiene nada del otro mundo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el archivo que intentaba abrir se llamaba LISTADO_ALUMNOS cuando el verdadero archivo se llamaba LISTA_ALUMNOS, un error muuuuy boludo, pero bueno, asi son la mayoría de errores en esto

```
void buscar()
{
    FILE *f;
    f=fopen("lista_alumnos.dat","rb");
    cout << ("Ingrese el nombre del alumno a eliminar: ");
    char apellidoYNombre[50];
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(apellidoYNombre);
    alumno a;

    int existe=0;
    fread(&a, sizeof(alumno), 1, f);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        if (strcmp(apellidoYNombre,a.apellidoYNombre)==0)
        {
            cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
            cout << "Nombre........: " << a.apellidoYNombre << endl;
            cout << "Edad..........: " << a.edad << endl;
            cout << "Grado.........: " << a.grado << endl;
            cout << "Dojo..........: " << a.dojo << endl;
            cout << "Kumite........: " << a.kumite << endl;
            cout << "Kata..........: " << a.kata << endl;
            cout << "______________________________________" << endl;
            existe=1;
        }
        fread(&a, sizeof(alumno), 1, f);
    }
    if (existe==0)
        cout << ("No existe un alumno con dicho nombre\n");
    fclose(f);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Si el archivo no se pudo abrir [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) devuelve un puntero nulo (`0`, `NULL` o `nullptr`, diferentes formas de decir lo mismo). Lo ideal sería que luego de llamar a `fopen`, inmediatamente verifiques que se pudo abrir. `if (f) { cout << "El archivo se abrió correctamente"; }` por ejemplo.

Comment: Por cierto, es recomendable usar las estructuras que C++ te brinda. Desde [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) hasta [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).